# How to let a user change their own username?

Tags: aegir, distributions

I can't seem to figure out how to let users change their own username. I'm running Aegir with about 10 Open Atrium sites. With permissions I've checked "change own username" for the master Aegir site, as well as the Open Atrium sites. For giggles, I enabled every role to "change own username"..

But when I try to change my username in OpenAtrium and click save, it confirms "changes have been saved", but the username doesn't actually change.  This has ballooned into a huge issue for us.  I'm hoping there is some obvious dumb thing I need to do.  Thoughts?

Comment: That's done in permissions. In Drupal 7, go to admin/people/permissions and look under User: Change own username.

Comment: I realize this should be obvious

Comment: Here you can see I "change own username" permission checked off for ALL Aegir and ALL Open Atrum roles. http://screencast.com/t/iLheAUAYJAvM

Comment: However when I change the username on my profile page and click save it doesn't change the username -- but it doesn't throw an error either. Just says "Changes have been saved."  Nope

Comment: Sorry. I guess I read/answered too quickly... :-(

Comment: No problem. I'm wondering if this is being caused by a drupal site (Open Atrium) is managed by a Aegir (Master drupal site)? Grasping at straws at this point...

Comment: Perhaps you should post your question directly here? http://community.aegirproject.org/discussion

Answer (score 1):

Changing a username inside a hosted site is completely up to the OpenAtrium Drupal installation.
Aegir does not usually interact with this.

I just verified that it works OK on a clean Aegir 3 install with a standard Drupal site.

So @Bisonbleu's comment seems correct:

> That's done in permissions. In Drupal 7, go to admin/people/permissions and look under User: Change own username.